# Google Play beta release app-Not available in your region

Tags: google-play

We created an app that is ready for beta testing, the app is published to a specific region and we have created a beta testers list, the url is generated and when you click on it  the user can otp in to be a tester, but when he goes to actually download the app it says that the app is not available in his country?

Answer (score 1):

We have this problem also. We have an app that is available only in Spain, and we want to have beta testers in Italy to test the app before we make it available to all public. I've just asked this to the support guy on `https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/` (there is a chat that appears at the bottom).

**My question:**

The app is available only in Spain but we want to have beta testers in Italy. Is this possible?

**Support answer:**

The country distribution refers to the whole app, not individual tracks (like beta or production). As a result, it is not possible to beta test in one country whilst the production version is in another country.

**Conclusion:**

It seems that you need to make it available to that region before people living on that region can install it and beta-test it.